# In Rails while using the `where` method, how to match only the year and month?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Normally, to select all the records with the same date we use something like this :

```
Bronze.where(regdate: Date.new(2014,03,03))
```

How can we use where to select only from the **year** and **month**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For month it would be:

```
date = # set your date here
Bronze.where(regdate: date.beginning_of_month...date.beginning_of_month + 1.month)
```

Analogically for year.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `mysql` then try `extract` function of SQL

```
Bronze.where('extract(year from regdate) = ? AND extract(month from regdate) = ?', year_parameter, month_parameter)
```

But if you are using `sqlite` then try this

```
Bronze.where("strftime('%Y', regdate) = ? AND strftime('%m', regdate) + 0 = ?", year_parameter, month_parameter)
```

Answer (score 0):

Or simply

```
Bronze.where(regdate: Date.new(2014,03,03)).select("YEAR(d) as year, MONTH(d) as month")
```

Where d is the column you want to extract year and month.